# Ember view with dynamic class names

Tags: ember.js

Considering the following:

Parent template:

```
{{view App.SomeView id="42" panelClass="default"}}
```

View template:

```
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-{{panelClass}}">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        {{name}}
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{description}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

View JS:

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'views/some-view'
});
```

How can I achieve output HTML where the panel class gets set properly? At the moment it doesn't work because it wants to bind, so it inserts the ember metamorph script tags, instead of just plain text for the panel class.

Also, the template is wrapped in an extra div. How would I modify it so that the ember-view wrapping div is actually the first div in the template (the one with col-md-3 col-sm-6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bind-attr` helper exists for that reason. [Here's](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/) the guide entry.

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":panel panelClass"}}></div>
```

Also, not sure if you can use a prefix on `panelClass` in the template. If might be easier just to use a computed property to add the `panel-` beforehand.

---

I'm sorry, I didn't see your second question about the extra div. The guide explains [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/) how to extend the element.

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['col-md-3', 'col-sm-6']
});
```

Comment: That's ace, thanks. Also, very much liking the automagic inheriting of scope, so I can do `{{#each arrayOfModels}}{{view App.SomeView}}{{/each}}`.